# Privileges required in a Db2 Java stored procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, permissions, db2

I'm creating a Java stored procedure in Db2.
I'm aware that whomever calls the procedure needs to be granted the 'execute' permission on the procedure.
However, which permissions are required for the inserts/updates/deletes/selects to tables from the Java code ?

In the doc I found: "If the package or routine contains static SQL statements, the privileges of the owner of the package are used for those statements. If the package or routine contains dynamic SQL statements, the authorization ID used for privilege checking depends on the setting of the DYNAMICRULES BIND option of the package issuing the dynamic query statements, and whether those statements are issued when the package is being used in the context of a routine" (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005478.html)
In another place I found: "JDBC and CLI share the same packages." and "CLI packages are automatically bound to databases when the databases are created".
I found these packages, like SYSSTAT and SYSSH200. The package owner is 'SYSIBM', DYNAMICRULES is 'R'.
So does this mean I have to grant insert/update/delete to SYSIBM ?

(I'm specifically looking at LUW at the moment, but later the procedure also needs to run on Db2 on Z.)

Thanks for any insights you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grant CRUD privileges to the authorization ID that invokes your stored procedure. There is no package created for the external stored procedure, so the discussion you quote does not apply.

Comment: There is no package created for the JDBC statements inside the Java routine, but as it was missing on 1 machine I saw that package SYSSTAT is actually used. So does your answer mean that the quoted routine privilege checking does not apply to these JDBC/CLI packages ? Is there any documentation that further explains this Java stored procedure security topic ?

Comment: Still didn't find further/more specific documentation, but all my attempts confirmed the answer of @mustaccio, so I'm accepting it.
The doc I quoted in my questions doesn't seem to apply, or only in special cases - I'm still unsure ...